# Update DOM value whenever input value is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking through someone else's code where they update some value's whenever a value has been changed.  The actual code looks like the following.  Is there any reason to ever do this?  If so, what is it doing?

```
$("#inputID").on("change", function () {
    parent.document.getElementById("inputID").value= this.value;
});
```

Comment: What type of input is it?

Comment: It's possible they meant to put some sort of validation in that function and just forgot to do it. Other then that...

Comment: I think this a kind of updating the `iframe` input.  not sure since the code is using `parent.document`

Comment: from the looks of it, this code is running in a child window(ie a page opened by window.open/iframe) and when ever inputID value is changed a corresponding field in the parent page is updated

Comment: @user1671639.  The code is for adding files to tinymce, and yes it is related to an iframe.  Why does a iframe require something different?

Comment: @ArunPJohny  Didn't realize the iframe was relevant, but obviously it is.  So, is `parent` the DOM around the iframe?

Comment: yes... `parent` is the window which contains the iframe in this case

Comment: @user1032531 To be precise consider the 2 windows.  1. parent with `inputID` textbox 2. iframe(within the parent) with a input element `inputID` textbox.  Changing the `iframe` text value should also update `textbox` the parent.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense.  I take it the two inputs do not need the same ID, right?  Is it common to have inputs in both windows which need to share the same value?

Answer (score 0):

This could be used in a scenario for 2 properties that initially should be in sync. Consider a property (for example form label) that is set by an admin. The label has to have internal representation that makes sense to admin, and external "pretty" representation for the user. Initially when label name is typed in, using method above is synced and the same value e.g.

```
Last Name:
Last Name:
```

is populated both input boxes. If nothing changes, admin simple saves both values (having typed only one) and then admin and user see the same label. But later user's representation can be changed to

```
Please Enter Family Name:
```

But the admin's representation remains

```
Last Name:
```

for ease of access and manipulation.

Comment: Thanks Yuriy.  Sounds like for this case it more has to do with iframes. Otherwise, why use `parent`.